# How to access masterpage function from within content page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following function in my master page (tried to follow this link: http://www.braintrove.com/id/17/page/3):

```
public void PopulateMessageSlider()
{
    strSql = @"";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(str))
    {
        //function
    }
}
```

I am trying to access the function from my content page like this:

```
Site stMaster;
stMaster = (Site)Page.Master.Master;
stMaster.PopulateMessageSlider();
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
MyProject.Pages.ContentPage1.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +279
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +70
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3177
```

How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: Why did you do `Page.Master.Master` instead of `Page.Master`? Do you have nested master pages?

Comment: No just one master page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do it like this.

In your Content Page:

```
<%@ MasterType virtualpath="~/YourMasterPage.master" %>
```

In your Code Behind:

```
Master.PopulateMessageSlider();
```

More information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0%28v=vs.140%29.aspx).

Comment: I have this: `<%@ MasterType TypeName="MyProject.Pages.Site" %>`. Is that going to work the same way?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge Why ask? Why not just try and see?

Answer (score 1):

Change `stMaster = (Site)Page.Master.Master;` to `stMaster = (Site)Master;`. You don't have a nested master page, so no need to access the master of the master.

Additionally, if the master page type isn't going to change at runtime, you can set the [MasterType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228274(v=vs.100).aspx) on your page. That avoids the need for a cast and you can simply do `Master.PopulateMessageSlider();`.

Comment: Upvote for using my code to show a solution. Thanks.